# Separate background images at top and bottom of site?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have separate background images on the top and bottom of my site but can't quite seem to nail it. I would like the images to stay at the absolute top and bottom of the page.Below is a shot of the site mockup, and a shot of the backgrounds on their own with dimensions.

The mockup doesn't show it, but there will be text links and copyright info at the bottom. You can find my failed attempt at coding at www[dot]dev[dot]arbitersoflight[dot]net

Mockup
img683[dot]imageshack[dot]us/img683/4502/mocky[dot]jpg

Backgrounds
img233[dot]imageshack[dot]us/img233/1293/94210454[dot]jpg

Note: The backgrounds are 1200x400 each.

EDIT: At this point I can get the two images to show up without fail, the problem is getting the bottom image to stick to the absolute bottom of the browser window. It seems that it is currently at a fixed position. Below is my CSS and HTML..

UPDATE (Solved): I finally solved this by reworking my code based on this guide: http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ Thanks for all of the suggestions everybody.

Comment: Looks to me like you have it working.. What specifically is the issue?

Comment: Does the footer need to be sticky? I can't really tell what's the problem here?

Comment: The bottom background seems to be static, I'd like it to stay at the absolute bottom of the page.

Comment: I am really not sure to understand what you are looking for but the background-attachment css property might help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the second image as the body background, set a color too, and the first image as the container's background. Or vice-versa, but remember to align the background, and if you switch, mind the container's height.

The body and html background (like the suggestions from zzzzBov and nemophrost) don't work in my Firefox...

```
body {
    background: #DDD url('2.png') no-repeat center bottom;
}
.container {
    background: url('1.png') no-repeat center top;
}
```

Comment: I've done something similar, but this is still not putting the bottom image on the bottom of the browser window. It seems to just stay put regardless...

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is set a background image on the body and on html.

```
body {
    background: url(...);
}

html {
    background: url(...);
}
```

You can see [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/) for an example of this.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

The menu is a div with an own background to fit the upper area.
Then apply the background with the bottom part to the body or content/page container that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
html
{
  background: url(...) no-repeat top; /* see the background-position property */
}

body
{
  background: url(...) no-repeat bottom;
}
```

you may want to switch one or both to use `repeat-x`, and make sure you set a suitable background color to match the color on the images.

Comment: I tried this, but it is still displaying the bottom background at (what appears to be) a fixed position. I'm trying to get it to stick to the bottom.

Comment: Sounds like the body isn't expanding to contain the content. You don't have the html or body height set explicitly somewhere do you?

Comment: @Ferret it looks fine on my machine. The bottom image is centered behind the footer text, although why does layout.css have `html, body {height: 100%;}`?